# If memory-optimised tables always live in RAM, how do they survive a server reboot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, memory-optimized-tables

I clearly have a missing piece in my understanding of in-memory OLTP. Suppose that I have a memory-optimised table that is set up to persist both schema and data. Given that these tables always live in RAM, how does their data survive a server reboot? I've looked over the documentation, but I cannot recall seeing any mention of how or when their data is moved to disk. Indeed, as far as I know, the whole point of hekaton is that they don't live on the disk.

Have I simply missed a piece of documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory optimized tables come in 2 flavors:

DURABILITY = { SCHEMA_ONLY | SCHEMA_AND_DATA }

Both types survive a server reboot, but for SCHEMA_ONLY, no data is saved, but the table definition is. SCHEMA_AND_DATA preserves both the data and the schema.

Despite the recovery model, all DML for SCHEMA_AND_DATA memory-optimized tables is fully logged (except for index changes). Upon server reboot/instance restart, data is streamed from the data files (that exist as part of the memorty-optimized filegroup) from storage into memory.

I've blogged extensively about memory-optimized tables at http://nedotter.com/archive/category/in-memory-oltp/

Comment: _Upon server reboot/instance restart, data is streamed from the data files (that exist as part of the memorty-optimized filegroup) from storage into memory._ - That's the bit that I need. Give me a citation for that (e.g. the docs) and that's a complete answer.

Comment: [Is this the relevant documentation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/checkpoint-operation-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: That link you posted is for LSN/checkpoint, but if you want to understand durability for memory-optimized objects, you should check this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/durability-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver16